# .NET Reflector freezes when exporting dll

Tags: .net, dll, reflector

I have this problem with .NET Reflector that when I try to export a dll file (even if I didn't modified it yet) it  doesn't finish exporting it and it just freezes, I can't close the window, and if I click stop it stops exporting but doesn't let me close the window neither. I have to close the program from the task manager. [Trying to export unmodified dll, stops at LevelStorage.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6s5KS.png)

This is the dll file: [Assembly-CSharp.dll](https://ufile.io/dlyee)

Comment: Are you using a paid and up-to-dated version? It has been many years since I used the last free version of .NET Reflector. And is your dll extra large?

Comment: I'm using the newest version, the free trial. I attached the dll to the post